# string return a substring possibly with .find()

Tags: c++

Replace the two dots by code, which will return "over" from string `yay` to string variable `over`.

```
string yay = “semester almost over”; 

string over = ..
```

Confused by the question, the previous q's used `.find()` and it was simple, this one isn't even compiling.

Comment: Show what does not compile.

Comment: string over = yay.find("over");

Comment: I tried rearranging it in a cout statement before it'd run, which only gives me the position. I don't know if this is what the question is asking.

Comment: @JaredY Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please!

Comment: You did not even bother to give us the error message. Or, um, the code that "isn't even compiling". So I cannot even bother to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it is that is not compiling for you, but this is what you want:

```
string over = yay.substr(yay.find("over"),4);
```

To break it down: yay.find("over") returns index of the first letter of "over" in 'yay', which is 16. yay.substr(16,4) extracts 4 characters from 'yay' starting at index 16.

```
string over = yay.find("over");
```

Does not work because yay.find does not return a string, it returns an index